# Do I need a Nextcloud client on my Linux computer to access the photos synced from my iPhone?

Tags: linux, iphone, nextcloud

I want to sync my photos from my iPhone to my Linux computer. It seems that Nextcloud is a good option for this task (it might be a little overkill though).

Of course, I'll need to download the app to my iPhone and install a nextcloud server on my linux computer. My question is: Do I need a Nextcloud client in addition to the Nextcloud server on my Linux computer?

Can I just configure the server to save the photos in my home folders photo folder and am good to go, or is this a task I need the client for?

I fear that if I need both the server and the client, I'll end up with my photos duplicated on my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you do not need the client on the server.  The server software is what the remote clients connect to.  The client is not needed for the server to work.

There could be some cases where you would install the client on the server.  Perhaps you want to connect to a *different* NextCloud server to sync data.  Another reason would be if your server is also a workstation for users and they could access the data through the client.

Comment: "Another reason would be if your server is also a workstation for users..." - I think this is the use case I'm describing, or not? There is no extra, dedicated server in my setup, just my single linux computer on which I wish to not only store, but also access my photos.

Comment: @user1785730 So the server is your desktop computer, then why would you need a client?  The files are on your PC.  You dont need the client to access them.